# How to prevent current employer from finding out I am job searching?

Tags: job-search, job-change

When job searching, I update my resume on a few job sites. On three occasions, I've noticed the behavior of my boss and a few others changing (them being nicer to me) when I've posted my resume. I also get calls from recruiters, and sometimes I've felt certain such calls were not from someone who genuinely wanted to recruit me, but wanted to find out whether I was job searching or why I was leaving my current job. I started saving such phone numbers and have received calls from them at least once more (even after I deactivated my profile from the job site where they said they saw my resume).

Do companies do this? Do or can they have someone from a recruitment firm inform them if an employee has updated their resume and is actively job searching?

I know job sites have features to block certain employers, but even though I've done that, they seem to know. Perhaps because the recruitment is managed by a third party headhunting firm. If companies do have people who inform them in this manner, is there any way I can prevent them from finding out?

Perhaps another way to ask the question would be: "How can I know whether the company monitors employee job searches and through which firm or job board they do it?".

Comment: Companies will track that.  Do you really blame them?   You could apply under a fake name but that could cause other big problems.

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi - I am not so sure this always happens, I know for instance by law companies are not allowed to do that in Germany. There may exist people that do however., since this is difficult to enforce

Comment: @Vampire Did I say it *always* happens?

Comment: One thing you could do is to regularly update your resume whether you are actively job searching or not. That way, when you are 'really' searching, the situation will not appear any different than it has been for the whole time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend that instead of posting your resume to passive sites, you should double-down on applying to jobs at specific companies through their websites, or making your linkedin profile as wonderful as possible. You can turn off the "publish changes' option on linkedin, so that your connections are not notified of your updates.

Answer (score 5):

There's really not a lot you can do, unfortunately. At some point, someone's going to offer you a position that will seem really attractive to trap you (that is, if someone were actually trying to catch you at something). And then you've confirmed it.

Honestly, don't worry about it. Make your desk seem "homey" and personal. Treat everyone like you love it there and so on.

I don't see it as a negative if an employer thinks that employees might be looking elsewhere. It may cause them to examine the state of the company. And if they're so insecure that an employee considering other positions makes them treat you differently, that can be a signal that maybe there are better places to work.