# Applying for a new job; how to avoid company contacting current employer?

Tags: job-search, salary, negotiation

I'm applying for a new job in an effort to get a higher salary by means of new employment with a new company or having my current company match the offer.

I don't want any prospective employers to contact my current company and jeopardize my employment. How do I word this on my application or in an interview?

Comment: Most people looking for new jobs are in situations like yours. Therefore, it is usually understood that employment applications are confidential unless otherwise mentioned. Of course, that doesn't mean all companies respect that, but there likely nothing you could write to make them.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [Can a recruiter tell my company I am looking for a new position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139977/can-a-recruiter-tell-my-company-i-am-looking-for-a-new-position), and [How to prevent current employer from finding out I am job searching?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84055/how-to-prevent-current-employer-from-finding-out-i-am-job-searching)

Comment: Have you spoken with your manager about a salary increase? If you take your manager by surprise by demanding an increase by way of having another job offer, you're not likely to get a warm reception.

Comment: "or having my current company match the offer."  This may seem like a good idea and your company may match simply because they don't currently have a replacement for you but this is usually temporary fix and the moment that they do find a replacement you will likely be replaced.

Comment: That's fine. I'm looking for employment out of state as my primary focus. I'm just underpaid because I'm young, so if I can make more in the meantime I should go for it

Answer (score 13):

I tend to add 'References available on request' at the end of my CV. That gives the notion that you will let them talk to somebody if the interview process goes far enough. I think though it also hints you would rather they didn't just go and contact anyone off their own back.

Answer (score 1):

Usually resume sent with header "In Confidence" that implies that you don't want to  them to contact your current employer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, companies don't often contact references until they're seriously considering making an offer. Background check providers also typically respect requests to not contact one's current employer.

Comment: Also, ensure no conflicts of interest. I once interviewed for a company which, unknown to me at the time, was a client of my then employer. Even though the company had no intention of hiring anyone ultimately (they scrapped the position), they still got in touch with my employer who then threatened to fire me.